# How to pass $state var from parent state into child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

**Plnkr link https://plnkr.co/edit/6dLIk1vq6M1Dsgy8Y4Zk?p=preview**

[image]

#### Expected

After <kbd>Login</kbd> selecting a Ticker should send that ticker object into the Tags state. Which would then init the Tags state, and code will check which ticker had been selected/passed in and then show the appropriate tags list.

#### Results

Selecting a ticker does not update the Tags state nor do anything.

Note in screenshot below, no component or state logs after clicking a Ticker button:

[image]

---

#### What I've tried (From in the tickers.component controller):

```
$scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
    console.log(' Ticker clicked!', $state)
    $state.go('tags', { ticker: ticker });
}
```

and

```
$scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
    console.log(' Ticker clicked!', $state)
    $state.go('tickers.tags', { ticker: ticker });
}
```

---

#### Tickers module

```
// Tickers module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var tickers = angular.module('tickers', ['ui.router'])

  tickers.config(function($stateProvider) {

    const tickers = {
      parent: 'dashboard',
      name: 'tickers',
      url: '/tickers',
      params: {
        ticker: {}
      },
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'tickers-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('TICKERS view $state');

            $scope.tickers = [
              { id: 1, ticker: 'AAPL' },
              { id: 2, ticker: 'GOOG' },
              { id: 3, ticker: 'TWTR' }
            ];

            $scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
              console.log('ticker', ticker)
              $state.go('tags', { ticker: ticker });
            }
          }
        },
        'tags@tickers': {
          templateUrl: 'tags-template.html',
          controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('TAGS view $state');
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $stateProvider.state(tickers);
  })
  tickers.component('tickersModule', {
    templateUrl: 'tickers-template.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('TICKERS component');
      $scope.tickers = [
        { id: 1, ticker: 'AAPL' },
        { id: 2, ticker: 'GOOG' },
        { id: 3, ticker: 'TWTR' }
      ];

      $scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
        console.log(' Ticker clicked!', $state)
        $state.go('tags', { ticker: ticker });
      }
    }
  });
```

#### Tickers template

```
<div class="tickers-state">
  <div class="fl w100">
    <em>Tickers state</em>    
  </div>

  <div class="tickers-panel">
    <div class="tickers-list">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="ticker in tickers" class="fl">
          <button ng-click="clickTicker(ticker)">{{ ticker.ticker }}</button>
        </li>
      </ul>      
    </div>
  </div>

  <tags-module class="fl"></tags-module>

</div>
```

#### Tags module

```
// Tags module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var tags = angular.module('tags', ['ui.router'])
  tags.config(function($stateProvider) {

    const tags = {
      name: 'tags',
      url: '/tags',
      params: {
        ticker: {},
        tag: {}
      },
      parent: 'tickers',
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'tags-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('Tags view $state', $state.params);
            const tags_model = [
              {
                ticker: 'AAPL',
                tags : [{ id: 1, term: 'iPhone 7' }, { id: 2, term: 'iPhone 8' }, { id: 3, term: 'Tim Cook' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'GOOG',
                tags : [{ id: 4, term: 'Pixel' }, { id: 5, term: 'Pixel XL' }, { id: 6, term: 'Chrome Book' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'TWTR',
                tags : [{ id: 7, term: 'tweet' }, { id: 8, term: 'retweet' }, { id: 9, term: 'moments' }]
              }
            ];

            function matchTags(ticker, model) {
              return model.filter(function(obj){
                if (obj.ticker === ticker) { return obj; }
              });
            }

            $scope.tags_model = matchTags($state.params.ticker.ticker, tags_model)[0];

            $scope.clickTag = function(tag) {
              $state.go('tags', { tag: tag });
            }

            console.log('Tags init', $state.params);
          }
        },
        'view@tags': {
          templateUrl: 'view-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('VIEWS view $state');
            $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
          }
        },
        'chart@tags': {
          templateUrl: 'chart-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('CHART view $state');
            $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
          }
        },
        'social@tags': {
          templateUrl: 'social-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('SOCIAL view $state');
            $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $stateProvider.state(tags);
  })
  tags.component('tagsModule', {
    templateUrl: 'tags-template.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('TAGS component', $state.params);
    }
  });
```

[Full code in the Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6dLIk1vq6M1Dsgy8Y4Zk?p=preview)

Comment: your plunker keeps giving this error in console: TypeError: Cannot read property 'term' of undefined. I remember resolving it in your earlier question. can you fix this and update your plunker?

Comment: @leon the screenshot that you have attached doesn't show any error about switching states. but in your plunkr I get `Could not resolve 'tickers.tags' from state 'container'` which actually makes sense because tickers has a parent called "dashboard"..

Comment: Hmm I'm not getting any errors, I clicked the Freeze button, maybe that will fix it?

Comment: Does this work?

https://plnkr.co/edit/QNp7NbZpLi27KrFDdiS0?p=preview

Comment: One obvious issue is that you have mentioned that parent of tickers is dashboard but there is no state dashboard. After I change the parent of tickers to be container, it finds the hierarchy of states defined which is container->tickers->tags

Comment: @clever_bassi in your plnkr link I can see you are passing the Ticker not the Tag into those 3 views. I'm trying to pass the tag. And yeah also trying to properly create the dashboard state.

Comment: ok I'm offline for next 24 hours. If nobody helps you by then, I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: np! I got it working finally!!! :D child states and proper named views! https://plnkr.co/edit/CFbkPAlL2kVMSM3G4q5T?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**https://plnkr.co/edit/CFbkPAlL2kVMSM3G4q5T?p=preview**

I finally got child states setup correctly, as well as using properly named views:

```
// Container module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var container = angular.module('container', [ 'ui.router' ])
  container.config(function($stateProvider) {

    const container = {
      name: 'container',
      url: '/container',
      templateUrl: 'container-template.html',
      controller: function($scope, $state) {
        console.log('CONTAINER STATE');
        // $state.go('dashboard', {});
      }
    }

    const dashboard = {
        name: 'container.dashboard',
        // deepStateRedirect: true,
        // sticky: true,
        views: {
            'dashboard': {
                template: '<dashboard-module></dashboard-module>'
            },
            'feed': {
              templateUrl: 'feed-template.html',
              controller: function($scope) {
                console.log('FEED STATE');
              }
            }
        }
    }

    $stateProvider
      .state(container)
      .state(dashboard);
  });

// Dashboard module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var dashboard = angular.module('dashboard', [ 'ui.router' ])

    dashboard.config(function($stateProvider) {
      const dash_default = {
        name: 'container.dashboard.default',
        url: '/dashboard',
        template: '<tickers-module></tickers-module>',
        controller: function() {
          console.log(' DASHBOARD.DEFAULT STATE')
        }
      }
      $stateProvider.state(dash_default);
    })

    dashboard.component('dashboardModule', {
    templateUrl: 'dashboard-template.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('DASHBOARD component');
    }
  });

// Tickers module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var tickers = angular.module('tickers', ['ui.router'])

  tickers.config(function($stateProvider) {

    const tickers = {
      // parent: 'dashboard',
      name: 'container.dashboard.tickers',
      url: '/tickers',
      params: {
        ticker: {}
      },
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'tickers-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log(' TICKERS STATE', $state);

            $scope.tickers = [
              { id: 1, ticker: 'AAPL' },
              { id: 2, ticker: 'GOOG' },
              { id: 3, ticker: 'TWTR' }
            ];

            // $state.go('tags', { ticker: $scope.tickers[0] });

            $scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
              console.log(' >>> ticker view state', ticker)
              $state.go('container.dashboard.tickers.tagslist', { ticker: ticker });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $stateProvider.state(tickers);
  })
  tickers.component('tickersModule', {
    templateUrl: 'tickers-template.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('TICKERS component');
      // $scope.tickers = [
      //   { id: 1, ticker: 'AAPL' },
      //   { id: 2, ticker: 'GOOG' },
      //   { id: 3, ticker: 'TWTR' }
      // ];

      // $scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
      //   console.log(' Ticker clicked!', $state)
      //   $state.go('tags.list', { ticker: ticker });
      // }
    }
  });

// Tags module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var tags = angular.module('tags', ['ui.router'])
  tags.config(function($stateProvider) {

    const oldtags = {
      name: 'tags',
      url: '/tags',
      params: {
        ticker: {},
        tag: {}
      },
      // parent: 'tickers',
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'tags-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('Tags view $state', $state.params);
            const tags_model = [
              {
                ticker: 'AAPL',
                tags : [{ id: 1, term: 'iPhone 7' }, { id: 2, term: 'iPhone 8' }, { id: 3, term: 'Tim Cook' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'GOOG',
                tags : [{ id: 4, term: 'Pixel' }, { id: 5, term: 'Pixel XL' }, { id: 6, term: 'Chrome Book' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'TWTR',
                tags : [{ id: 7, term: 'tweet' }, { id: 8, term: 'retweet' }, { id: 9, term: 'moments' }]
              }
            ];

            function matchTags(ticker, model) {
              return model.filter(function(obj){
                if (obj.ticker === ticker) { return obj; }
              });
            }

            $scope.tags_model = matchTags($state.params.ticker.ticker, tags_model)[0];

            console.log(' $scope.tags_model', $scope.tags_model)

            $scope.clickTag = function(tag) {
              $state.go('tags', { tag: tag });
            }

            console.log('Tags init', $state.params);
          }
        },
        'list@tags': {

        },
        'view@tags': {
          template: '<view-module ticker="$ctrl.ticker"></view-module>',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('VIEWS view $state');
            $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
          }
        },
        'chart@tags': {
          templateUrl: 'chart-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('CHART view $state');
            $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
          }
        },
        'social@tags': {
          templateUrl: 'social-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('SOCIAL view $state');
            $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    const tags = {
      name: 'container.dashboard.tickers.tagslist',
      url: '/tags',
      params: {
        ticker: {}
      },
      views: {
        'tags' : {
          templateUrl: 'tags-list.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log(' tags-list controller', $state)
            $scope.ticker = $state.params.ticker;

            const tags_model = [
              {
                ticker: 'AAPL',
                tags : [{ id: 1, term: 'iPhone 7' }, { id: 2, term: 'iPhone 8' }, { id: 3, term: 'Tim Cook' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'GOOG',
                tags : [{ id: 4, term: 'Pixel' }, { id: 5, term: 'Pixel XL' }, { id: 6, term: 'Chrome Book' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'TWTR',
                tags : [{ id: 7, term: 'tweet' }, { id: 8, term: 'retweet' }, { id: 9, term: 'moments' }]
              }
            ];

            function matchTags(ticker, model) {
              return model.filter(function(obj){
                if (obj.ticker === ticker) { return obj; }
              });
            }

            $scope.tags_model = matchTags($state.params.ticker.ticker, tags_model)[0];

            console.log(' $scope.tags_model', $scope.tags_model)

            $scope.clickTag = function(tag) {
              $state.go('tags', { tag: tag });
            }
          }
        },
        'view@tags': {
          template: '<view-module ticker="$ctrl.ticker"></view-module>',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('VIEWS view $state');
            $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $stateProvider
      .state(tags);
      // .state(tagslist);
  })
  tags.component('tagsModule', {
    templateUrl: 'tags-template.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('TAGS component', $state.params);
    }
  });

// ViewHeader module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var view = angular.module('view', ['ui.router'])
  view.component('viewModule', {
    templateUrl: 'view-template.html',
    bindings: {
      ticker: '<'
    },
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('VIEW component', $state.params);
      $scope.ticker = this.ticker;
      $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
    }
  });

// Chart module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var chart = angular.module('chart', ['ui.router'])
  chart.component('chartModule', {
    templateUrl: 'chart-template.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('CHART component', $state.params);
      $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
    }
  });

// Social module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var social = angular.module('social', ['ui.router'])
  social.component('socialModule', {
    templateUrl: 'social-template.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('SOCIAL component', $state.params);
      $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
    }
  });

// TickersApp module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var tickersApp = angular.module('tickersApp', 
  ['ui.router',
   'container',
   'dashboard',
   'tickers',
   'tags',
   'view',
   'chart',
   'social']);

tickersApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

  const login = {
    name: 'login',
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'login-template.html',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'l',
    controller: function($state) {
      this.login = function() {
        $state.go('container.dashboard.tickers', { });
      }
    }
  }

  $stateProvider
    .state(login);
})
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$state',
function($rootScope, $location, $state) {
    // $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
          // console.log(' ')
          // console.log('toState', toState)
          // console.log('state.current.name', $state.current.name)
          // console.log('toParams', toParams)
          // console.log('fromState', fromState)
          // console.log('fromParams', fromParams)
          // console.log('options', options)
      });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log('state.current.name', $state.current.name)
      })

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', 
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){
        console.error('ERROR toState', toState)
        console.error('ERROR fromState', fromState)
      });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound', 
      function(event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams){ 
          console.log('unfoundState.to', unfoundState.to); // "lazy.state"
          // console.log('unfoundState.toParams', unfoundState.toParams); // {a:1, b:2}
          // console.log('unfoundState.options', unfoundState.options); // {inherit:false} + default options
      });

    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', 
      function(event){
        // console.log('viewContentLoaded', event)
      });
}]);
```